# What is a word that encompasses both "extend" and "shrink"

Tags: single-word-requests

Instead of writing "You may extend or shrink the deadlines if you choose to", I would like a word that encompasses both.

However I do not want something as generic as "adjust" or "modify". The word should embody extending and shrinking.

Comment: "You may flexible the deadlines" does not work. It must be a verb that replaces "extend or shrink" and means the same thing.

Comment: shrink is not _the_ antonym of extend.  the antonym of shrink is grow.

Comment: Ok, I have removed my assertion that they are antonyms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two extremes  and want a common word to encompass them it generally needs to be "generic" in nature, however due to the need to convey a specific topic related freedom the common terms for adjusting deadline time could be

"alter" "change" or "vary"

> "You may **vary** the deadlines if you choose to"

shrink and expand are usually associated with a timeline chart or project plan and if that is the context of moving either boundary then an obvious modifier could be

"reposition"

> "You may **reposition** the deadlines if you choose to"

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, neither *extend* nor *shrink* should be used with *deadline* in the first place. (Although I understand the idiomatic use.) A deadline is something that happens at a fixed point in time, it doesn't have a duration. Instead, you extend or shrink the duration of a project or the period of time before a deadline is to occur. (A generic word that applies to both *extending* and *shrinking* is *resizing*—but that has more of a spatial sense than a temporal one.)

For deadlines, you would **reschedule** them:

> : to schedule or plan again according to a different timetable
> *especially* : to defer required payment of (a debt or loan)
>
> // She called to *reschedule* her appointment.
> // The meeting was *rescheduled* for Tuesday.

You can also simply say that you **move** deadlines.

Comment: How would you speak of moving a deadline forwards and backwards?

Comment: @Toothrot Either something like *I'm moving the deadline up* (shrinking the duration of the project) or *I'm moving the deadline back* (extending the duration of the project.) Don't ask me why *moving it up* means *pulling it closer*, or why, analogously, we don't say *moving the deadline down* when we want to delay it (*pushing it away*). Some things don't make complete sense, it's just how we say them.