# Things to do with a deadline

Tags: phrases

I was moved by [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475046/what-is-a-word-that-encompasses-both-extend-and-shrink/475059?noredirect=1#comment1198316_475059) to ask the following.

You can *move* a deadline.  But what verbs or expressions may be used to
express the movement of a deadline forwards and backwards in time?

> Don't know if I can finish this by Friday.  Would you mind if we --- the deadline?
>
> You seem to be almost finished.  Should we --- the deadline?

I would have guessed *extend* and *shorten* were normal, but they're not
quite logical, seeing as a deadline is a line you pass.

Comment: You can always use *put back* and *bring forward* if you feel that way.

Comment: @Minty, and to put the deadline back is to move it forwards in time?

Comment: Further away from us in time - but yes the deadline moves in the direction of time's arrow.

Comment: You could use _postpone_ for moving it to a later date. Your second example makes no sense; if everyone has finished well before the deadline, it is no longer necessary and can simply be forgotten.

Comment: @KateBunting, I wrote _almost_ finished.
Keeping the original deadline might cause one to spend time perfecting
something good enough instead of moving on to a new task.
But I'm sure a better example could be devised.